# setState not updating React component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below in component's constructor:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            post: {},
            deleteModal: false
        }
    }
```

I am updating the state as below in componentDidmount:

```
componentDidMount(){
        fetch('https://snaptok.herokuapp.com/fetchPost/'+this.props.postId,{
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
              return response;
            } else {
              var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
              error.response = response;
              throw error;
            }
          },
          error => {
                throw error;
          }).then(res=>res.json()).then(res=>this.setState({
              post: res
          })).catch(err=>{console.log(err);})
    }
```

This is the res object:

```
{"_id":"60c0ac493175c10014e178d4","author":"Vipul Tyagi","email":"vipultyagi629@gmail.com","uid":"0FGD6CWHi6YnaE7an0MW0z9yk7p1","title":"This is a title","description":"This is a description.","file":"","fileType":"","subGratis":"Cricket","dateOfPost":"9-6-2021","likes":0,"comments":[],"__v":0}
```

But in the render method, `this.state.post` is still `{}`. I can confirm that res is not empty object( I have checked in network tab).
I don't know what is the problem in my code, is it the right way to set state of an empty object.

Please help me to correct the error, if any, in my code.
Thank You.

**EDIT**:
I put componentWillUnmount in the above component and found that this component is getting unmounted for no reason. And then it is not getting mounted again.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?  Can you provide a runnable example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Check it in useEffect

Comment: The above component is a part of a project. I am not sure whether same rror would be reproduced in another code.

Comment: @JagadishLenka I am using class component

Comment: @David There is no error in console.

Comment: Then check the value in next render in copmnentdidmount

Comment: show full code of your `componentDidMount()` method

Comment: @JagadishLenka the fetch request is happening in the componentDidMount itself. When I console ``this.state.post`` in the render, it prints ``{}`` two times( First time obviously because of initial state)

Comment: @GratisDevs: *"I am not sure whether same rror would be reproduced in another code."* - Then **that** is the first problem you need to solve.  Showing us random code which may or may not have anything to do with the problem and asking us to guess isn't going to get you far.  Your first step is to replicate the issue.  After all, if your attempt to replicate the issue with the code shown here doesn't actually replicate it, then how can we possibly know the problem from the code shown here?

Comment: check `res` - its probably not a json but a text?

Comment: @DmitriyFrolov I have updated the code.

Comment: Because it is not waiting for promise to complete , you can console that thing in second .then for testing

Comment: @JagadishLenka I have already tested that thing.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the problem is in function context `this`.

May be you can try such that:

```
componentDidMount(){
    const setState = this.setState;
    fetch('https://snaptok.herokuapp.com/fetchPost/'+this.props.postId,{
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        } else {
          var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
          error.response = response;
          throw error;
        }
      },
      error => {
            throw error;
      }).then(res=>res.json()).then(res=>setState({
          post: res
      })).catch(err=>{console.log(err);})
}
```